# Tikz error when using \textwidth to specify length

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
        \newcommand{\s}{5}
        \begin{figure}
            \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \fill[Goldenrod] (0,0) rectangle (0.6*\s, 0.6*\s);
                \fill[Goldenrod](0.6*\s, 0.45*\s) rectangle (0.8*\s, 0.55*\s);
                \fill[Goldenrod](0.6*\s, 0.25*\s) rectangle (0.8*\s, 0.35*\s);
                \fill[Goldenrod](0.6*\s, 0.05*\s) rectangle (0.8*\s, 0.15*\s);
                \draw (0.25*\s,0.3*\s)  edge[out=45, in=180, red]  (0.6*\s, 0.5*\textwidth);
                \draw (0.25*\s,0.3*\s) edge[out=0, in=180, green] (0.6*\s,0.3*\s);
                \draw (0.25*\s,0.3*\s) edge[out=-45, in=180, blue] (0.6*\s,0.1*\s);
                \node[text width=1cm, anchor=west] at (0.6*\s,0.5*\s) {\footnotesize  \color{red}$\lambda_1$};
                \node[text width=1cm, anchor=west] at (0.6*\s,0.3*\s) {\footnotesize  \color{green}$\lambda_2$};
                \node[text width=1cm, anchor=west] at (0.6*\s,0.1*\s) {\footnotesize  \color{blue}$\lambda_3$};
                \shade[inner color=white,outer color=Goldenrod] (0.3*\s,0.3*\s) circle (0.2*\s);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

The newly defined variable `\s` does not cause any problems, but the use of `\textwidth` to specify coordinates makes Tikz throw an error(I copied from TexStudio directly):

```
line 22: Missing \endcsname inserted. }
line 22: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `.' or `.1' (in '0.5*\textwidth .180'). }
line 22: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `.' or `.1' (in '0.5*\textwidth .180'). }
line 22: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `.' or `.1' (in '0.5*\textwidth .180'). }
line 22: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `.' or `.1' (in '0.5*\textwidth .180'). }
line 22: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `.' or `.1' (in '0.5*\textwidth .180'). }
line 22: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `.' or `.1' (in '0.5*\textwidth .180'). }
```

I am very curious about the reason behind this, I would be glad if someone sheds some light on this.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem. Related maybe: https://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2012-August/019579.html. Maybe you should point out that there are two `\textwidth` in the code and only one causes the problem (`(0.6*\s, 0.5*\textwidth);`).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks for the feedback. The `\textwidth` in the `\resizebox` command does not seem to be relevant with the error I am experiencing. I think the link you provided went unanswered.

Comment: It did not went unanswered (I just don't understand the answer). Follow the "Next message:" at the bottom.

Comment: The issue is similar actually, in order to follow through I should reproduce it as my TeX knowledge a bit limited.

Comment: Then maybe add the code from there (maybe better organized) to your question and refer to the source (Heiko Oberdiek is also mentioned, he is very famous here).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect you want by using `\textwidth` in a relative, rather than an absolute, coordinate specification.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\s}{5}
\begin{figure}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \fill[Goldenrod] (0,0) rectangle (0.6*\s, 0.6*\s);
      \fill[Goldenrod](0.6*\s, 0.45*\s) rectangle (0.8*\s, 0.55*\s);
      \fill[Goldenrod](0.6*\s, 0.25*\s) rectangle (0.8*\s, 0.35*\s);
      \fill[Goldenrod](0.6*\s, 0.05*\s) rectangle (0.8*\s, 0.15*\s);
      \draw (0.25*\s,0.3*\s)  edge[out=45, in=180, red]  +(0.35*\s,{0.5*\textwidth-0.3*\s});
      \draw (0.25*\s,0.3*\s) edge[out=0, in=180, green] (0.6*\s,0.3*\s);
      \draw (0.25*\s,0.3*\s) edge[out=-45, in=180, blue] (0.6*\s,0.1*\s);
      \node[text width=1cm, anchor=west] at (0.6*\s,0.5*\s) {\footnotesize  \color{red}$\lambda_1$};
      \node[text width=1cm, anchor=west] at (0.6*\s,0.3*\s) {\footnotesize  \color{green}$\lambda_2$};
      \node[text width=1cm, anchor=west] at (0.6*\s,0.1*\s) {\footnotesize  \color{blue}$\lambda_3$};
      \shade[inner color=white,outer color=Goldenrod] (0.3*\s,0.3*\s) circle (0.2*\s);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: relative coordinate specification]

Note that it would probably be wiser to use, for example, `font=\footnotesize, text=blue` rather than `\footnotesize \color{blue}` and so on. Especially be cautious with the use of `\color` unless you really need it because you can't do what you need without it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what exactly causes Tikz not to understand `\textwidth` directly? Does it not expand when necessary or something?

Comment: @Vesnog I'm not sure. But it does not recognise a dimension expression as part of a coordinate specification. It at least needs the dimension expression to be turned into a number and units, say, as in Zarko's suggestion. Or you can use it, as here, where you are adding a dimension, where that works, too. But I did not follow up on the technical complications and I probably wouldn't understand them if I tried.